# How to create array in foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, simple-html-dom

I am using PHP HTML DOM Parser to get data from another site. First i get URLs of my trades on this site  and than i send another request on each trade url to get comments .I want to make an array of comments so i can sort them later. Why i cant create array ?

It looks like this

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$result = array();
$html = file_get_html('http://csgolounge.com/profile?id='.$steamid);

foreach($html->find('div.tradepoll') as $trade) 
    {
    $tradeid = $trade->find('.tradeheader')[0]->find('a')[0]->href;
    $html = file_get_html('http://csgolounge.com/'.$tradeid);       

        foreach($html->find('div.message') as $message)
        {

        if($message->find('p',0)){}

        else
           {                    
            $left = $message->find('.msgleft')[0];
            $right = $message->find('.msgright')[0];

            //information about comments
            $time = trim(strip_tags_content($left->innertext));
            $text = $left->find('.msgtxt')[0];

            $result[$time]['time'] = $time;
            $result[$time]['text'] = $text;                     
           }

        }

    }

    echo json_encode($result);
```

If i echo $time or $text i always get data successfully.

Comment: So what's the problem? `$result` is array that you want. isn't it? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Yes i want to create array in foreach loop with comments. The problem is that echo json_encode($result); returns nothing.

Comment: If you `var_dump($result);` is it what you expect?  Perhaps json_encode is falling over on non utf-8 encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem.

The Simple HTML DOM Parser does not clean up memory in the DOM each time file_get_html or str_get_html is called so it needs to be done explicity each time you have finished with the current DOM.

So I added $html->clear(); at the end of the loop.

Credits: [electrictoolbox.com](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-simple-html-dom-parser-allowed-memory-exhausted/)